# Unit and integration testing in perl using Test::More - how to capture exit call?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, csv, testing

I have this script that converts a file from csv delimited to pipe delimited (csv2pipe.pl). 
The pipe delimited file then gets loaded into database.
I am trying to run unit testing for it (csv2pipe_unit_test.pl with test call like(main()...) . 
Function sub main() in csv2pipe.pl has exit call if there is no parameter supplied. 
Unfortunately it is not possible to capture exit call in testing call so the testing program just exits. 
I cannot do eval { code }. It does not catch exit call. It will catch die and any errors but not exit. 
The same with package Capture::Tiny from CPAN. It does not catch exit call. 
Any ideas how to test this main() sub and catch exit call?

File: csv2pipe.pl

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

#--------------------------
# all work done in main sub
#--------------------------
unless (caller) { main(); exit; }

sub main {
    printf( "START---$0---%s---\n", scalar( localtime(time) ) );

    if ( scalar(@ARGV) < 4 ) {
        print "Usage: $0 -i file.csv -o file.pipe\n";
        exit;
    }

    my %options = ();
    getopts( "i:o:", \%options );
    my $file_out = $options{o} or die "Missing -o param";
    my $file_inp = $options{i} or die "Missing -i param";

    if ( !-f $file_inp ) {
        die "Could not find file to parse ($file_inp)\n";
    }

    my $row_ctr = 0;
    open( FH_inp, "<$file_inp" ) or die "Could not open file: $file_inp";
    open( FH_out, ">$file_out" ) or die "Could not open file: $file_out";

    my ( $str, $ret );
    foreach $str (<FH_inp>) {
        $row_ctr++;
        #print "str=$str";
        $ret = csv2pipe($str);
        #print "ret=$ret";
        print FH_out $ret;
    }

    close(FH_inp);
    close(FH_out);
    print "Processed $row_ctr rows\n";

    printf( "END---$0---%s---\n", scalar( localtime(time) ) );
    printf( "Program Run Time: %s second(s).\n", ( time - $^T ) );
}

# convert csv to pipe
sub csv2pipe {
    my $str = shift;
    return undef if !defined $str;
    #print ''.(caller(0))[3]."\n";
    $str =~ s/,/|/g;
    if ( $str =~ /"/ ) {
        while ( $str =~ /".*?"/ ) {
            my $beg   = $`;
            my $match = $&;
            my $end   = $';
            $match =~ s/"//g;
            $match =~ s/\|/,/g;
            $str = $beg . $match . $end;
        }
    } elsif ( $str =~ /'/ ) {
        while ( $str =~ /'.*?'/ ) {
            my $beg   = $`;
            my $match = $&;
            my $end   = $';
            $match =~ s/'//g;
            $match =~ s/\|/,/g;
            $str = $beg . $match . $end;
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

File: csv2pipe_unit_test.pl

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

# enter main test loop
run_tests();
exit;

sub run_tests {
    printf( "START---$0---%s---\n", scalar( localtime(time) ) );

    require_ok "csv2pipe.pl";

    ok( csv2pipe('') eq '',                                 'test empty string' );
    ok( csv2pipe('a') eq 'a',                               'test one char' );
    ok( csv2pipe('a,b') eq 'a|b',                           'test two chars' );
    ok( csv2pipe('a,b,abc,def,') eq 'a|b|abc|def|',         'test multiple strings' );
    ok( csv2pipe("abc,def,abc'xyz") eq "abc|def|abc'xyz",   'test single quote in string' );
    ok( csv2pipe('abc,def,abc"xyz') eq 'abc|def|abc"xyz',   'test double quote in string' );
    ok( csv2pipe('abc,def,"abc,xyz"') eq 'abc|def|abc,xyz', 'test double quoted comma does not get converted' );
    ok( csv2pipe("abc,def,'abc,xyz'") eq 'abc|def|abc,xyz', 'test single quoted comma does not get converted' );

    # this call does not work!!!
    # exit in csv2pipe.pl function main() will exit this testing script as well
    like(
        main(),        # first  param = argument to program
        qr/Usage:/,    # second param = expected result
        'test run program with no parameter'
    );                 # 3rd parameter = test description

    print "Tests Executed: ";
    done_testing();
    printf( "END---$0---%s---\n", scalar( localtime(time) ) );
    printf( "Program Run Time: %s second(s).\n", ( time - $^T ) );
}
```

Normal output of testing:

```
C:\workspace\csv2pipe>c:\perl\bin\perl csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl
START---csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl---Fri Sep 12 15:15:47 2014---
ok 1 - require 'csv2pipe.pl';
ok 2 - test empty string
ok 3 - test one char
ok 4 - test two chars
ok 5 - test multiple strings
ok 6 - test single quote in string
ok 7 - test double quote in string
ok 8 - test double quoted comma does not get converted
ok 9 - test single quoted comma does not get converted
Tests Executed: 1..9
END---csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl---Fri Sep 12 15:15:48 2014---
Program Run Time: 1 second(s).
```

Output of testing when it fails in sub main() exit:

```
C:\workspace\csv2pipe>c:\perl\bin\perl csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl
START---csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl---Fri Sep 12 15:20:49 2014---
ok 1 - require 'csv2pipe.pl';
ok 2 - test empty string
ok 3 - test one char
ok 4 - test two chars
ok 5 - test multiple strings
ok 6 - test single quote in string
ok 7 - test double quote in string
ok 8 - test double quoted comma does not get converted
ok 9 - test single quoted comma does not get converted
START---csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl---Fri Sep 12 15:20:49 2014---
Usage: csv2pipe_unit_testing.pl -i file.csv -o file.pipe
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
```

Comment: You can convert a CSV to pipe delimited *much* more easily using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). You're re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END), but have you considered using an `END` block to mitigate early exits?

Comment: Also note that `Don't use exit to abort a subroutine if there's any chance that someone might want to trap whatever error happened. Use die instead, which can be trapped by an eval.` as seen [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html).

Comment: 1. I can’t use Text::CSV because it is not installed on the target Solaris system at work. 
I don’t have permission to install any new packages.I can download and install packages to my home directory but not to project directory (project is running under different user id). So when my program goes to production it will not work because the library is not there.

Comment: 2. Thank you for the advice, I did not think about END {} block.
3. Yes, I can change the code from exit to die. Then I can capture with eval. But what if I am testing some old legacy script that was written long time ago. I do not want to touch the old code; I just want to write some unit testing for it.

Comment: There are Test::Fatal and Test::Exception for testing `die` with, and Test::Warn for testing warnings (although it's a bit flaky with multi-line warnings).

Answer (score 4):

If you can't turn your `exit` into a `die`, try [`Test::Trap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Trap). From the synopsis:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Trap;

my @r = trap { some_code(@some_parameters) };
is ( $trap->exit, 1, 'Expecting &some_code to exit with 1' );
is ( $trap->stdout, '', 'Expecting no STDOUT' );
like ( $trap->stderr, qr/^Bad parameters; exiting\b/, 'Expecting warnings.' );
```

Comment: This sounds promising I will try to use this and post back. Thank you.

Comment: my @ret = trap { main(); };
 like ($trap->stdout, qr/Usage:/ , 'test run program with no parameter');

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! Please accept the answer (click the tick) if it did.